# Accessing button id from custom layout in android

Tags: android

I have a custom layout file that has a button. I want to access it in another class how to do that?

Comment: Your layout need to bind with the activity or fragment in order to get the information of view. Using data binding or SetContentView(). You can't get the view information which is not the part of current class view.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is wrong, the button in the activity can only be operated through the activity itself, otherwise there will be a risk of memory leaks. You can use the method of extensive, interface callback to complete the operation of this button.